# Pandas dataframe output in Indian comma style

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have followed the tips given in *https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148853/convert-an-amount-to-indian-notation*

to be able to display a number in Indian comma format where `123456789` would be displayed as `1,23,34,56,789` using the command:

```
print("INR {}".format(currency_in_indian_format(123456789))).
```

However I have not been able to have this feature extended to display all values in a pandas dataframe. Is there any way this could be done by modifying the command:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an *Indian Rupee*, use:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
print(format_currency(123456789, 'INR', locale='en_IN').replace(u'\xa0', u' '))
```

Output:

```
₹ 12,34,56,789.00
```

*Note - your expected output has the number 3 repeated twice, hence doesnot match with mine.*

Comment: Thanks a lot Anky_91. I understand how the conversion can be done for an individual variable, but could this conversion be done to en entire dataframe or individual columns of a dataframe., say  print(format_currency(df), 'INR', locale='en_IN').replace(u'\xa0', u' ')) ?

Comment: Yes. You can use the apply function for that

Comment: I tried to use apply method and it did not work so I created a function that would do it element by element for specified columns and recreate the dataframe.